# Python: How to evaluate variable at function call

Tags: python, variables, global, evaluate

I would like to access the global variables of a sibling module, i.e. it's name.
My current situation:

logger.py

```py
import logging
def get_logger():
    return logging.getLogger(__name__)
log = get_logger()
```

main.py

```py
from logger import log
```

The logger's name will naturally be 'logger.py'. Although I would like it to be 'main.py'.
Now my first guess was to pass a function instead that would call `eval("globals()['__name__']")` and have it executed in the sibling module after the import, so that it could then be evaluated. Without luck.

By now, I have come to the conclusion that this approach is rather ugly and that it would simply be easier to write:

```py
import logger
log = logger.get_logger(__name__)
```

Yet, it really bugs me that this is something that I have not figured out how to achieve. Is this even possible in python?

Comment: In "traceback" module there are "extract_tb" and "extract_stack" which may help to find out the callers module.

Comment: No, the name will be `logger`; `__name__` is the name of the module, not the file that defined the module. `logger.py` has *no*  knowledge of who might use it; if you want a logger named `main`, you need to pass an argument to `get_logger`.

Comment: @chepner that much I had figured out myself.
I guess something like traceback might be the only solution